# Define a function t, which takes ad its argument a propositional formula and returns the set of propositional variables in that formula

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

How to give a recursive definition of a a function t, which takes ad its argument a propositional formula and returns the set of propositional variables that occur in the given formula?

Answer (score 1):

We have to follow te recursive def of *formula*.

*Basis* : If $\varphi := p_i$, then $\text {Prop_Vars}(\varphi) = \{ p_i \}$.

*Induction step* :

*(i)* If $\varphi := \lnot \psi$, then $\text {Prop_Vars}(\varphi) = \text {Prop_Vars}(\psi)$.

*(ii)* If $\varphi := \psi \lor \tau$, then $\text {Prop_Vars}(\varphi) = \text {Prop_Vars}(\psi) \cup \text {Prop_Vars}(\tau)$;

and so on for the other binary connectives.

---

Let $\text {Wff}$ the set of formulae and $\text {Vars}$ the set of propositional variables $p_i$.

Then :

> $\text {Prop_Vars} : \text {Wff} \to \mathcal P(\text {Vars})$.